# Performance: Android Webview vs Views Datasource + parsing JSON

Tags: android, drupal, android-webview, drupal-views

If a developer is only looking to display specific Views blocks, rather than full webpages, would it seem worthwhile to rebuild the content as XML directly from the output of a Views datasource? Webview seems easier to implement, but I have a feeling it would lead to extra load times and overhead.

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer it is not possible to understand the complexity of your web page that you wish to display, but beware that the usage of WebView may lead to a lot of compatibility issues.

If your webpage is easy to implement natively - I'd recommend going native way. From the performance standpoint it would be the best solution anyway.

If your webpage is complex, check out the [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) project. It's XWalkView is much more reliable than WebView. Beware, that the downsides of this way would be:

- Bigger apk size, from my experience not less than +=20Mb
- RAM overhead
- Extra time on XWalkView instantiation